# How can I change the line spacing on a longtable using multicolumn?

Tags: longtable, multicolumn

I want my document to be doublespaced but the cells in my longtable I need them to be singlespaced. I don't know how to do this in this enviroment.
All the examples I have seen so far are not using longtable neither multicolumn. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe=false,,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%START TABLE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{longtable}{|p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}|}

    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\makebox[17cm][r]{\textit{Continuação da página anterior}}}\\ \hline
    \endhead

    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\makebox[17cm][r]{\textit{Continua na próxima página}}}\\
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot

    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Atividade:}} \\
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\parbox{17cm}{Verificar o \textit{deployment} dos ISEs e validar suas funções.}} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Tempo:}} \\
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{5 minutos} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Comando:}} \\
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\parbox{15cm}{N/A}} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Resultado Esperado:}} \\
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\parbox{15cm}{\lipsum[1]}} \\ %need to be singlespace
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{} \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle. The table has other lines that I cut off to shorten the example. These other lines use up to 6 columns and when they`re not needed, I go with multicolumn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose `longtable`in

```
\begin{singlespace}

... your long table ...

\end{singlespace}
```

[image]

Comment: That's also correct. Thank you @Zarko. I will let your answer to be the corrected one.

Answer (score 1):

I was simples than I thought. 
Follow the answer.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe=false,,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell,multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%START TABLE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{longtable}{|p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}|}

    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\makebox[17cm][r]{\textit{Continuação da página anterior}}}\\ \hline
    \endhead

    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\makebox[17cm][r]{\textit{Continua na próxima página}}}\\
    \endfoot
    \endlastfoot

    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Atividade:}} \\
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\parbox{17cm}{Verificar o \textit{deployment} dos ISEs e validar suas funções.}} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Tempo:}} \\
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{5 minutos} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Comando:}} \\
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\parbox{15cm}{N/A}} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Resultado Esperado:}} \\
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\parbox{15cm}{\singlespace \lipsum[1]}} \\
    \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{} \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: you have single space only in one cell ... which contain command `\singlespace`. If you like to have whole table single spaced, than you should use my answer, or search for solution for similar question on site. Your question is for sure duplicate.